# In How Many Ways Can 7 Toys Be Given To 3 Children When Each Child is eligible for all the toys

Tags: permutations, combinations

In How Many Ways Can 7 Toys Be Given To 3 Children When Each Child is eligible for all the toys?

Answer is 2187 but How???

Comment: Presumably all toys are distinct (e.g. you have a toy train, a ball, a doll, etc...)  Notice that $2187 = 3^7$.  To explain the answer, give the first toy to a child.  How many ways can this be done?  Give the second toy to a child.  How many ways can this be done?  etc... Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

Comment: Technically this has nothing to do with permutations or combinations specifically, but instead falls under a much broader category of what we call enumerative combinatorics.  The technique used of multiplication principle is more fundamental than applying permutations or combinations and should be learned before either of those terms were ever introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Each toy may go to any child with same probability. Hence the number of possibilities for each toy is $3$. This is true for each toy, and there are $7$ toys, hence total number of ways$=3^7=2187$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a natural bijection between each way to give the toys to the children and the set of functions with domain $\{\text{toy1, toy2, toy3, ... toy7}\}$ and codomain $\{\text{child1, child2, child3}\}$.

The set of functions with domain $\{\text{toy1, toy2, toy3, ... toy7}\}$ and codomain $\{\text{child1, child2, child3}\}$ is represented as $\{\text{child1, child2, child3}\}^{\{\text{toy1, toy2, toy3, ... toy7}\}}$ and has cardinality $|\{\text{child1, child2, child3}\}|^{|\{\text{toy1, toy2, toy3, ... toy7}\}|}=3^7=2187$

Alternatively worded, we approach via multiplication principle.  Pick which child receives toy1, pick which child receives toy2, etc... There are three options for each toy.  Multiplying the number of options available for each step, we have a count of $3\times 3\times\dots\times 3 = 3^7=2187$

Comment: Why answer such an easy question with bijection (and with more mathematical jargon) when tou can give a direct argument.